# Simple attendance list SQL schema architecture advice

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, jpa, database-design

I have a sport club presence list on paper which I have to bring online.
Basically, I have everything in handle except the SQL schema architecture.

I have never designed a DataBase and I'm not sure if it's the right way. I appreciate any help!

> If the person is present we make a x with a pen on paper :)
> To do to look the same like on the paper but in an app I try to develop a Java Vaadin App with Spring Data JPA-Hibernate.
>
> **On paper and in the future APP look like this:**

[image]

> And this is the MySQL schema:

```
create table person(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar(20)
);

create table isPresent(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
isPresent boolean
);

create table persons_isPresent(
person_id int,
isPresent_id int,
FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
REFERENCES person(id),
FOREIGN KEY (isPresent_id)
REFERENCES isPresent(id)
);

create table training(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
person_id int,
isPresent_id int,
training_time datetime,
FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
REFERENCES person(id),
FOREIGN KEY (isPresent_id)
REFERENCES isPresent(id)
);
```

I have never designed a DataBase and I'm not sure if it's the right way. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Title is vague. Rewrite to summarize your specific concern.

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean, "the SQL schema architecture"? How exactly are you stuck trying to produce exactly what? PS Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite one. That is too broad. Follow one & ask a question where stuck. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: where do you see code in image? The tabel above is from paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unnecessary to have `ispresent` ID's.

I would keep your `Person` table as is.

Create a `Training` table with an ID and time, and an `TrainingAttendance` table with a Training ID and a Person ID. If you want to check a person's attendance at a training, check if a record exists in `TrainingAttendance` with the Person's ID and the Training ID.

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    PERSON_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TRAINING (
    TRAINING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    TRAINING_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TRAINING_ATTENDANCE (
    TRAINING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PERSON_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(PERSON_ID) REFERENCES PERSON(PERSON_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TRAINING_ID) REFERENCES TRAINING(TRAINING_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(TRAINING_ID, PERSON_ID));
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Bianconi, it looks like you're right!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be cleaner to think about training sessions independently. Then you could achieve that with three tables [training]<-[attendee]->[person], where the attendee is a binding table. So maybe something like this:

```
create table training(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
training_time datetime
);

create table person(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar(20)
);

create table attendee(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
person_id int,
training_id int,
FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id),
FOREIGN KEY (training_id) REFERENCES training(id)
);
```

I tried it out with some simple inserts/select and it might do the trick for you?

```
insert INTO person (first_name) VALUES ('Pavel');
insert INTO training (training_time) VALUES (NOW());
insert INTO attendee (person_id, training_id) VALUES (1,1);

select person.first_name, training.training_time
from attendee, person, training 
where person.id = attendee.person_id 
AND training.id = attendee.training_id;
```